# Multiple order by inside groups

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I register user's performance on some games(lets call it 'scores'. The table is basically: id, id_user, id_game, game_level, score and time.

Then I have a table (lets call it 'games') where I store the game info, basically: id, name, levels, description and so on.

So, what I need now is to get the best results (score desc, time asc) for each game and level pairing for a determined user, while retrieving the game info from games table.

What I tried was:

```
SELECT id_game
     , game_level
     , score
     , time 
  FROM scores 
 where id_user = 4 
 order 
    by id_game asc 
     , game_level asc
     , score desc
     , time asc
```

And I get all the results ordered exactly how I want. Then I use it as a derived table to order the results, like this:

```
SELECT * 
  from 
     ( SELECT id_game
            , game_level
            , score
            , time 
         FROM scores 
        where id_user = 4 
        order 
           by id_game asc
            , game_level asc
            , score desc
            , time asc
       ) A 
   group 
      by id_game
       , game_level
```

And it does group, but it doesn't show the first result of each set (highest score and lowest time). I thought maybe it would show the last result on groups, so I tried reversing the score logic, but didn't work as well.

What am I doing wrong, and is there a simpler way to do it?

Ps.: I didn't even try to join the games table to get game info since I wasn't able to get the results I wanted.

OK, here's sample data:

```
+----+---------+------------+-------+-------+---------+
| id | id_game | game_level | score | time  | id_user |
+----+---------+------------+-------+-------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |          1 |    70 | 01:20 |       4 |
|  2 |       1 |          1 |    70 | 01:17 |       4 |
|  3 |       1 |          2 |    66 | 00:44 |       4 |
|  4 |       1 |          2 |    64 | 00:22 |       4 |
|  5 |       1 |          3 |   100 | 03:24 |       4 |
|  6 |       1 |          4 |    99 | 01:29 |       4 |
|  7 |       1 |          4 |    99 | 01:23 |       4 |
+----+---------+------------+-------+-------+---------+
```

And here is the expected result:

```
+---------+------------+-------+-------+
| id_game | game_level | score | time  |
+---------+------------+-------+-------+
|       1 |          1 |    70 | 01:17 |
|       1 |          2 |    66 | 00:44 |
|       1 |          3 |   100 | 03:24 |
|       1 |          4 |    99 | 01:23 |
+---------+------------+-------+-------+
```

I found many answers explaining how to do this for one order by argument, but none for two.

Comment: Please include sample data and expected output in your question

Comment: What you're doing wrong is thoroughly covered in the manual, as is the remedy :-(

Comment: This is an old (an dirty) trick, which might not work in newer versions any more.

Comment: Yeah, the question you guys marked this one as duplicate of doesn't answer my question. And if this is covered in the manual can you tell me where? Because I tried a lot of options before coming here to ask for help.